# Want to know what a redeliver policy configuration in a mule does to file endpoint connector

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have a flow like this [image] with first file endpoint from left had configuration like this [image]  had set redeliver policy to 5. To make this flow to fail I had configured unknown file location on the second file connector from the left. If I configured redeliver policy to 5 on the first file connector what happens exactly. why we are using redeliver policy. Am not asking what happens exactly to this flow. But in generalized manner   what exactly redeliver policy does on inbound file endpoint connector.

Answer (score 1):

The re-delivery policy is a filter which can be applied to any source component. When you add a re-delivery policy basically you are doing a check at the source itself to catch/identify certain errors or to fulfill certain conditions before the actual mule message get passed on to the next components in the flow.

if you sent the redelivery policy to 5 the connector will try redeliver the message 5 times and if it encounter "bad message" 5 times after the 5th try it will throw MULE:REDELIVERY_EXHAUSTED error.

the actual process work in the following manner:
Each time the source receives a new message, Mule identifies the message by generating its key. During this process if the flow encounters an error Mule increments the counter associated with the message key and when the limit specified is reached it throws the error.

with respect to File connector an example would be how many times you want to retry to access a file before you want the connector to give up.

Comment: i.e For a given input directory. for input file endpoint if it  was not able to pickup from input directory. it will try for max re delivery count and then it fails the flow or deployment is that you are saying

Comment: yes. you got it. thanks for the upvote, if you find my answer helpful may be you can accept it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: I tested redeliver strategy for jms by sending jms server to offline mode . it tried until it reached max redeliver count but I did same for file by mentioning wrong directory it was not trying until to max  times. it is  failing by saying it is not a directory.

Comment: let me tryout a sample